# tablesorter header set to sort false, but still sorts

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I implemented the jquery tablesorter and am trying to set one column to not sort. I followed the documentation but something isn't working because it still sorts. Here is the code.

I copied the whole function but I am pretty sure you only need the code inside the get.

```
function displayPid() {
        var x = $("#selectPub").val();

        if (x == 0) {
            return;
        }

        $.get('content_backend_pub_pid_2_5.ashx', { cmd: '2', pubid: x }, function(o) {
            $("#inputDiv2").html(o);
            $(".sortable th").addClass("sort_header");
            $(".sortable").tablesorter({ widgets: ["zebra"], headers: { 3: { sorter: false}} });
            $(".sortable tr").mouseover(function() { $(this).addClass("over"); });
            $(".sortable tr").mouseout(function() { $(this).removeClass("over"); });

        });
        //$("#inputDiv4").html("");
        //displaySelectMid();
    }
```

Also, I tried another alternative. I added the jquery.metadata.js file and in the th tag I wrote...

```
class="{sorter:false}"
```

That did not work either. I am thinking it has something to do with my css styles?

And this is the html it produces...

```
<th id="editheader" class="{sorter:false} sort_header header">Edit </th>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is `tablesorted` previously set in that same table? With that code you're disabling the sorter for the 4th column (it's zero based). Have you tried using `2` instead?

Comment: I know it is zero based, and I have tried to 2 already :(

Comment: Side note: Problems like this are why I just pass data back from Ajax calls and not HTML.

Comment: Great... I guess I will keep that in mind next time I am developing an interface...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I finally figured it out. I forgot I had a couple hidden th's in my code, so it was working but it was setting the sorter false to a hidden row! Lol! I changed the index to 5 and it works great.

I am so dumb, I am really dumb, for real.  ;-)